# How to merge two laser scan line images gathered from same height in opencv?

Tags: python, c++, image, opencv, correlation

So say we have two images like this:

[image]
[image]
(This two will not correlate)

How can we understand that they can be correlated (merged into one) so  that one would extend the other using opencv?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding where these two even align, so it's hard to help. Can you manually overlay where they are supposed to align, as an expected output?

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question and improve it as it is hard to understand. Thank you.